# Python Compare Two Key/Value Pairs

Tags: python, list, key-value

Ive got two sets of key value pairs that look like this:

```
tom = {'coffee': 2, 'hotdog': 1}
```

and another like this:

```
namcat = {'hotdog stand':[hotdog, foodstand], 'cafe':[breakfast, coffee]}
```

Id like to compare whenever a key associated with 'tom' is the same as a value in 'namcat', and if so add 1 to a running total. I think its iterating over key-value pairs with lists that is causing me issues.

Comment: Could you please put the code example, which you get errors. It's really hard to understand your purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for k, v in namcat.items():
    for item in v:
        for key, value in tom.items():
            if value == item:
                running_total += 1
```

Demo:

```
>>> hotdog = 1
>>> coffee = 2
>>> foodstand = 6
>>> breakfast = 10
>>> tom = {'coffee': 2, 'hotdog': 1}
>>> namcat = {'hotdog stand':[hotdog, foodstand], 'cafe':[breakfast, coffee]}
>>> running_total = 0
>>> for k, v in namcat.items():
    for item in v:
        for key, value in tom.items():
            if value == item:
                running_total += 1


>>> running_total
2
```

This should do it. Hope it helps!

Comment: Using 'if value == item' I get 0, however 'if key == item' works for me, and logically makes sense to me, can you explain the reason?

Comment: Are you sure? That shouldn't happen. The right way is to compare `value` with `item`.

Comment: Because `key` is `"coffee"`, and item is the content of `coffee`, which is a `1`. But `value` contains `1` and it would be equal with the content of `coffee`.